# How cluster perceived changing of host ip when system is continuous running?

Tags: load-balancing, distributed-system

Image below scenario:

Some hosts forms a cluster, and there is a load-balance layer above cluster, but in distributed system, hosts crash are gonna happen, my question is how cluster perceive change of ip so that load-balancer could route requests to working hosts but not crashed ones.

Comment: Hope that someone could point it out in a clear way